# flutter bottomNavigationBar and custom font problem

Tags: flutter

I try to create `bottomNavigationBar` with the custom font but application crash.

if remove `bottomNavigationBar`, `Text` widget display correctly with font but after add `bottomNavigationBar` application crash.

**flutter version**

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-IR)
```

**code**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF6F8FA),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Tab 1",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "iransans"),)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access), title: Text("Tab 2",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "iransans"),)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.offline_bolt), title: Text("Tab 3",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "iransans"),)),
      ]),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Hello from tab 1"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Error**

```
[VERBOSE-2:FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
[VERBOSE-2:FontFamily.cpp(184)] Could not get cmap table size!
[VERBOSE-3:FontCollection.cpp(95)] nTypefaces == 0
```

Comment: It should work, maybe its a conflict with IOs. I just ran your code and it works with no exceptions.

Comment: @Hosar Which flutter channel do you use?

Comment: I've tested your implementation and for me it's working fine, I've downloaded the font and add it into a test app. Make sure the font files are not corrupted or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I forget to add `uses-material-design: true` after `flutter` in `pubspec.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the font to the `pubspec.yaml` file and you are using an iOS simulator, then this issue is very similar to the one mentioned as an issue on the Github page ([Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26108)) .

Comment: My custom font works in `body` `Text Widget` but when add `bottomNavigationBar` application crash. I also have this problem in Android simulator and real device.

Comment: Have you checked the Flutter logs ? That could lead us in some direction. The above code works completely fine for me with the same version of Flutter as mentioned by you above.